# How to download latest version of software from same url using wget

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep, wget

I would like to download a latest source code of software (WRF) from some url and automate the installation process thereafter. A sample url like is given below:-

http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3.6.1.TAR.gz

In the above url, the version number may change time to time after the developer release the new version. Now I would like to download the latest available version from the main script. I tried the following:-

```
wget -k -l 0 "http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/" -O index.html ; cat index.html | grep -o 'http:[^"]*.gz' | grep 'WRFV'
```

With above code, I could pull all available version of the software. The output of the above code is below:-

```
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV2.0.3.1.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV2.1.1.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV2.1.2.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV2.1.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV2.2.1.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV2.2.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3-Chem-3.0.1.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3-Chem-3.0.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3-Chem-3.1.1.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3-Chem-3.1.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3-Chem-3.2.1.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3-Chem-3.2.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3-Chem-3.3.1.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3-Chem-3.3.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3-Chem-3.4.1.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3-Chem-3.4.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3-Chem-3.5.1.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3-Chem-3.5.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3-Chem-3.6.1.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3-Chem-3.6.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3-Var-do-not-use.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3.0.1.1.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3.0.1.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3.1.1.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3.1.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3.2.1.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3.2.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3.2.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3.3.1.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3.3.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3.4.1.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3.4.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3.5.1.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3.5.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3.6.1.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3.6.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3.TAR.gz
http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3_OVERLAY_3.0.1.1.TAR.gz
```

However, I am unable to go further to filter out only later version from the link.

Comment: `sort -V | tail -n 1`

Comment: `wget -k -l 0 "http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/" -O index.html ; cat index.html | grep -o 'http:[^"]*.gz' | grep 'WRFV' | sort -V | tail -n 1` results in sorting different file. It gives me `http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3_OVERLAY_3.0.1.1.TAR.gz` which is not I wanted. rather I would expect `http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV3.6.1.TAR.gz`

Comment: it requires intelligence. not a good job for regex. you need to have a script and maintain it from time to time.

Comment: There are tools like Debian's [uscan](https://wiki.debian.org/debian/watch) but it has its peculiarities (it basically assumes you want to build a Debian package, and has some hard-coded defaults specific to this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, for processing the html-pages i recommendig some perl tools, but because this is an *Directory Index* output, (probably) can be done by bash tools like `grep` `sed` and such...

The following code is divided to several smaller bash functions, for easy changes

```
#!/bin/bash

#getdata - should output html source of the page
getdata() {
    #use wget with output to stdout or curl or fetch
    curl -s "https://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/"
    #cat index.html
}

#filer_rows - get the filename and the date columns
filter_rows() {
    sed -n 's:<tr><td.*href="\([^"]*\)">.*>\([0-9].*\)</td>.*</td>.*</td></tr>:\2@\1:p' | grep "${1:-.}"
}

#sort_by_date - probably don't need comment... sorts the lines by date... ;)
sort_by_date() {
    while IFS=@ read -r date file
    do
        echo "$(date --date="$date" +%s)@$file"
    done | sort -gr
}

#MAIN
file=$(getdata | filter_rows WRFV | sort_by_date | head -1 | cut -d@ -f2)
echo "You want download: $file"
```

prints

```
You want download: WRFV3.0.TAR.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a numeric sort and taking the top line:

```
   wget -k -l 0 "https://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/" -O index.html ; cat index.html | grep -o 'https:[^"]*.gz' | grep 'WRFV[0-9]*[0-9]\.[0-9]'  | sort -r -n | head -1
```

Displays higher version number (not the newest by date/time):

```
   https://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/src/WRFV4.0.TAR.gz
```

Comment: it breaks easily. what if the maintainer releases a new version called `WRFV4.TAR.gz`?

Comment: That is the problem with screen scraping, you at the mercy of the site updater.